# How to upgrade Ubuntu using the Live CD?

Tags: upgrade, 9.10, 9.04

I installed Ubuntu 9.04 on my desktop, an year ago.

Can I upgrade from Ubuntu 9.04 to Ubuntu 9.10 using the Ubuntu 9.10 Live CD?

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot upgrade Ubuntu using the Live CD.

However, you can upgrade using the [Ubuntu Alternate Install CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads).

Read this Ubuntu Community Documentation: [How to Upgrade from Ubuntu 9.04 to Ubuntu 9.10](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KarmicUpgrades). 
You can download Ubuntu 9.10 Alternate Install CD from the [Ubuntu 9.10 releases page](http://releases.ubuntu.com/karmic/).

**Note**:  
Ubuntu 9.10 will not be supported beyond April 2011.

- Normal releases, server or desktop, are supported for 18 months.
- LTS (Long Term Support) releases are supported for 3 years on the desktop and 5 years on the server.